# How can be scraped using PHP curl a webpage with infinite scroll?

Tags: php, curl, imgur

I'd like to know how can be scraped in a loop (page 1 page 2etc....) a webpage which has infinite loops (like imgur) for example ... ?

I tried the code below, but it returns only the first page. How can I trigger the next page due to infinite scrolling template?

```
<?php
    $mr = $maxredirect === null ? 10 : intval($maxredirect);
    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $mr > 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $mr);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

        if ($mr > 0) {
            $original_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
            $newurl = $original_url;
            $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);

            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
            do {
                curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
                $header = curl_exec($rch);
                if (curl_errno($rch)) {
                    $code = 0;
                } else {
                    $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    if ($code == 301 || $code == 302) {
                        preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
                        $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));

                        // if no scheme is present then the new url is a
                        // relative path and thus needs some extra care
                        if(!preg_match("/^https?:/i", $newurl)){
                            $newurl = $original_url . $newurl;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $code = 0;
                    }
                }
            } while ($code && --$mr);
            curl_close($rch);
            if (!$mr) {
                if ($maxredirect === null)
                    trigger_error('Too many redirects.', E_USER_WARNING);
                else
                    $maxredirect = 0;
                return false;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
        }
    }
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

$ch = curl_init('http://www.imgur.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec_follow($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cURL` works by getting the source code of a webpage. Your code will gather the HTML only from the original webpage. In the case of imgur, it will include ~40 images, plus the rest of the page layout.

This original source code doesn't change when you scroll down. However, the HTML inside of your browser does. This is done with AJAX. The page that you are looking at requests information from a second page.

If you use FireBug (for FireFox) or Google Chrome's page inspector, then you can monitor these requests by going to the Net or Network tab (respectively). When you scroll down, the page will make another ~45 requests or so (mostly for images). You'll also see that it requests this page:

[http://imgur.com/gallery/hot/viral/day/page/0?scrolled&set=1](https://imgur.com/gallery/hot/viral/day/page/0?scrolled&set=1)

The JavaScript on the imgur homepage appends this HTML to the bottom of the home page. You would probably want to query this page (or the API, as [the other Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/610573/chris) said) if you want to get a list of images. You can play with the numbers at the end of the URL to get more images.

Comment: Nice idea inspecting with Firebug ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Page scraping is seldom the best approach for reasons exactly like this. [Imgur offers an API](http://api.imgur.com/) which accomplishes the tasks I assume you're attempting without using any hacky scraping.

If you're married to the idea of scraping, you'll have to do some research. Instead of scraping only the main page, you'll need to note the API used by the AJAX request, you can call directly to that and continue to scrape subsequent pages of data. The specifics of this approach are beyond the scope of this answer, especially considering that there is an established API available.

**Related Reading**

- Imgur API - http://api.imgur.com/
- The questionable legality of unauthorized page scraping - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues

Comment: Ok, I understand that is convenient and easy to manipulate the imgur API but how can we manage with any other website with infinite scroll? Should we handle ONLY through AJAX requests?

Comment: If a public API is not offered, then that's how to do it, as the other Chris describes in more detail in his answer (and I mention here).