# How to get all the results from a web page just as the browser shows when finished scrolling down

Tags: http, curl, wget, pup

I'm trying to get all the video results from a web page :

```bash
$ curl -qs https://ok.ru/video/c335170 | pup '.video-card_lk attr{href}' | wc -l
24
```

Another method returns the same result :

```bash
$ wget --config="/dev/null" -qO- https://ok.ru/video/c335170 | grep -oP '/video/\d+' | sort -u | wc -l
24
```

EDIT 1: Scrolled the webpage to the end with firefox and saved it as `c335170.html` and I get the same result :

```bash
$ cat c335170.html | grep -oP '/video/\d+' | sort -u | wc -l
24
```

However, on the web browser, it shows, after the scrolling to the end, 81 results.

Same pb. with YouTube and the "Load more" button which hides results from http console clients :

```bash
$ curl -qs https://www.youtube.com/user/impacttvouaga/videos | grep -oP "/watch\?v=[\w-]+" | uniq | wc -l
21
```

EDIT 2: I've just saved this webpage with firefox as a "Web Page, HTML only" into `RMC_IMPACTV__YouTube.html` and then :

```bash
$ cat RMC_IMPACTV__YouTube.html | grep -oP "/watch\?v=[\w-]+" | uniq | wc -l
21
```

How can I have the remote HTTP server to give me all the results ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417994/how-can-be-scraped-using-php-curl-a-webpage-with-infinite-scroll

Comment: @peak Wouah, this is getting much more complicated than I thought. Do this mean I have to write a `https://ok.ru` specific PHP script to retrieve what I want ?

Comment: I'd try to find out whether ok.ru doesn't have an API so you can avoid all the complexities of simulating "on scroll" triggers.  (The simulation would not have to be done in PHP ...)

Comment: @peak First, I'd like to try something much more simple and save `https://ok.ru/video/c335170` with firefox as a `Web Page, HTML only` into `c335170.html` but somehow, `firefox` does not save all the results it shows into this file. Any idea why ?

Comment: You could try: browse, scroll to end, and then save.

Comment: @peak I did so, but it does not work and I don't understand why. Take a look at my EDIT1.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440965/how-to-curl-full-web-page-content

Comment: @peak I think I'll give console browsers (lynx, w3m, ...) a try before digging any deeper.

Comment: I was able to download the expanded HTML using the Chrome 'Developer Tools" interface, but it involves several steps ...

Comment: @peak I found this firefox addon : [Save Page WE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/). It works :-)

Comment: @peak This add-on is also available from Chrome : [Save Page WE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof)

Comment: @peak I've tried a few add-ons and it seems [Scroll it!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scroll-it/nlndoolndemidhlomaokpfbicfnjeeed/related) is the most appropriate I've found so far, when it comes to auto scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

To download the expanded html one I installed [Save Page WE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof) and to scroll down I installed [Scroll it!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scroll-it/nlndoolndemidhlomaokpfbicfnjeeed)